# How do I get back to the tavern after being asked to investigate the Cult of Akbaa?

Tags: arx-fatalis

I've been asked to go back to the Tavern and use the password on that door. I can't find a way to get back to the Tavern.

The [walkthrough](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=318768749) says to just walk back to the tavern, but there doesn't seem to be any path from the Human Kingdom back to the tavern. There's just no path to the North East.

The cave that leads to the Troll Kingdom doesn't have a new opening that allows you to go back.

The Goblin Kingdom's entrance to the starting dungeon is blocked.

The trolls in the Troll Kingdom say they cleared the collapsed cave that leads to the Human Outpost, but the opened passage is the entrance to Level 4 where I cleared the whole level and went further to the entrance of the Cult on another level.

I've even studied the [map](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=255908689), but I don't see any way to get back to the Tavern.